# MVC Create New Page Only if it Doesn't Exist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using .net MVC 3 razor to develop a web app and I would like to create a new page for the shopping cart only if it doesn't already exist. I have the following code:

```
<p class="button">
    @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart",
    "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.ToyId }, new { target = "_blank" })
</p>
```

The above code creates a new page however it will always create a new page even if the shopping cart page has already been created.

Is there a way to check if the page already exists and move to that page or create the new page if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do each of the following:

- Add this information to your Model
- Replace the action-link action with a simple js function that will ajax the server to check whether or not it already exists and act by it

*EDIT:* I think I didnt undersatnd your question - you want to open a new window only if this window is not currently open, what you shoud do is insted of _blank, place a simple string like "shopping_cart", this will automatically reuse the window

Comment: Your EDIT note was exactly what I was after.